VS Code Opens Wrong Virtual Environment After Restarting Terminal (Git Bash on Windows 11)
I’m new to VS Code and I’m trying to create a virtual environment for my project. I’m using Windows 11 and Git Bash as my terminal.
Steps I Followed

Navigate to the project directory:
My_Name MINGW64 /d/Projects/first_project


Create the virtual environment:
python -m venv venv


Activate the virtual environment:
source venv/Scripts/activate

At this point, I see:
(venv) My_Name MINGW64 /d/Projects/first_project


I select the interpreter in VS Code:

Select Interpreter ➔ Python ('venv': venv) .\venv\Scripts\python.exe



Everything works as expected until I close the terminal and start it again.
The Problem
When I reopen the terminal, instead of the virtual environment being active in the project directory, I see this:
(venv) My_Name MINGW64 C:/Users/My_Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code

It’s showing the virtual environment, but the directory has changed to the default location of VS Code, not my project directory. I’m not sure why this is happening.
What I Have Tried

Creating the Virtual Environment via VS Code

I used the "Select Interpreter" option in VS Code and chose "Create a virtual environment" and selected venv.
The same issue occurred.


Googled for Similar Issues

Most suggestions talk about activating the virtual environment, which I’m already doing.



Questions

Why is the virtual environment pointing to the default VS Code directory instead of my project directory?
How can I ensure that the terminal opens in the correct project directory with the virtual environment already active?
Is there a VS Code setting or Git Bash configuration I’m missing?

Any guidance or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!

Show environment contributions => PATH and PWD are different (maybe this is the problem but I don't know how to fix it)

If you are just closing the terminal window with the X button or Ctrl-', then the session is not destroyed. So when you open it again you are returned to the same session. You should first deactivate the virtual environment, or use the "Kill Terminal" icon (the trash bin).

I know. I tried to deactivate venv and start new session, but I see again "(venv) My_Name MINGW64 C:/Users/My_Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code"

Sorry but it is not possible to guess what is happening on your system. Can you gather some more precise details?

I think I have the same problem https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22908
